# Redirection after check all field inputs

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I create a simple registration form with check input validation and I want redirect to another page `You have successfully registered`, my check validation works but just for 1/2 second when a user presses the register button it show error message:

> You need enter username / email etc.

As I said, it only works for a few seconds, then redirect the user what's my problem I need know how I can make that  to keep users on the page until they enter username / email etc.

If that information is not entered it will not redirect  user to the page `you have successfully registered` Should I add a wait or pause option?

Here is the html button:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
     let url = "http://whatever/Successfullyregistration.html"
     window.location.href = url;
 });
```

Comment: Why are you setting the url directly and not using the form submission to redirect?

Comment: You have to return false if the validation fails in your submit event. Also the button does not require a click event and the redirection url can be set in the forms action attribute.

Comment: Don't handle the redirection in the JS, let the server redirect whenever it get's a valid form submit.

Comment: @epascarello One guy from this site  recommended it :) thanks to the rest others for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of taking the value of the input and checking it first. If the value is not blank then the page will redirect to your provided link.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (document.getElementById('input-text').value !== '') {
      let url = "http://whatever/Successfullyregistration.html"
     window.location.href = url;
  }
 });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="input-text" />
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm so glad it worked for you @aerochord! If you're happy with the answer go ahead and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)